# How to change CSS style without id or class

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want to change background of this 2 link 
`<a href="http://www.domain.com/index.html">
<a href="http://www.domain.com/index.php">`

But condition is I can't add any class or Div id here. I can't touch this this html code also. Just I need to add some css from external. I mean in main style.css sheet. Is is possible ? I have tried with this code `a { background:url(../images/image.png);}` but problem is it's change the whole link's background of the page. But I want 2 different background of the 2 link. Is is really possible. Anyone can help me please :)

Comment: Are they inside any element with `class` or `id`? You can try to select them looking for parents or childs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a way to **differentiate** the two links, from the code you posted, they only differ in the url they point to, so you could use this:

```
/* anchors with href attribute ending in index.html */
a[href$='index.html'] { background:url(../images/image.png);}

/* anchors with href attribute ending in index.php */
a[href$='index.php'] { background:url(../images/image2.png);}
```

Comment: OK I will do. Another question...If I want to change css style only one <P> tag then what should I do ? For example <P> Hi Nelson, How are you ?</p>  . Is it possible to change CSS of this <p> tag only ?

Comment: That `p` tag has nothing to be differentiated in CSS, you need to give more context, does that `p` tag have a unique parent or sibling tags? you could use those to select it with CSS..

Comment: No, I have many `p` tag in the page. I mean I want to change CSS only a single `p` tag within a full article. Is it possible ? I want to change `h2` tag also. But only in one page. I don't want to change global css of `h2` or `p` tag. Anyway thanks for your time :)

Comment: I understand what you want, but to make it possible you need some way to differentiate the p tag you want to change from the rest of p tags in the page. For the a elements we did use the href attribute value, but the p tag you posted has no attributes, so you may need to see if you can use a unique parent or sibling.

Comment: It can be done using the nth-child property. As an example, if your `p` tag is the third `p` tag inside a `<div class="article">` element, you could use this css `div.article > p:nth-child(3) { color: red; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Do you know any tips so that I can differentiate this `p` tag from other & can apply a different CSS on it. My `p` tag elements are very simple like "<P> Hi Nelson, How are you ?</p>" . Is it possible ? Can I differentiate `p` tag by using any special & unique symbol like`!@#` etc ?

Comment: Thanks great :) . But what will happened if I use same CSS class `article` in another page ? I think it will be apply on that page also :(

Comment: Paste the full html code in http://pastebin.com and paste the link here, tell me what p tag do you want and I can try to figure out how to select it with css..

Comment: Thanks you again. But I am working on Joomla CMS in localhost.

Comment: that's irrelevant, just do right click "View source" in your browser and copy/paste the html.

Comment: Hi, Here the link of the site in where I want to apply this [link](http://astroflix.com/) . I want to apply different CSS on this `Buy Movies` header may be `h1` tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `div.contentpaneopen > h1:nth-child(2) > span { color: red; }`

Comment: Another help please ... When you will visit this site you can see a side bar in right side. `Search AstroFlix....` etc. I have added an image on the background of the header but when I make my browser's window small the image come to the bottom of the word `Search AstroFlix` . Can you help me here also please.

Comment: Sorry I can't see the image you talk to, anyway I cannot help you more, try posting a new question, I hope my help so far have been useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS attribute selectors to only style links with an href that matches the links you supplied. Example:

```
a[href="http://www.domain.com/index.html"],
a[href="http://www.domain.com/index.php"]{
    background:url(../images/image.png);
}
```

You could also match all links with an href **starting with** http://www.domain.com using the following rule

```
a[href^="http://www.domain.com"]{
    background:url(../images/image.png);
}
```

Please check the support as older browser might ignore attribute selectors.

http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/